# How do I calculate a percentage using R studio

Tags: r, percentage

I have a data set that lists badbuy cars by state.  I want to calculate the top 10 states with the badcars by percentage per state

The code that isn't working is:

```
carDF2 = carDF %>% filter(!is.na(IsBadBuy)) %>% group_by(VNST) %>%
  mutate(PBadBuy = round(IsBadBuy/sum(IsBadBuy), 3))
```

Data Table:

[image]

Comment: It's not providing any data in the data table or graph.  I want it to group by state how many bad cars there were and calculate the percentage (badcar#/totalcar#) for each state and sort them from highest to lowest for the top 10 states.  Essentially using VNST and IsBadBuy values.

Comment: The value of `IsBadBuy` is `character` "No".  It's not clear how you divide a character string `isBadBuy/sum(IsBadBuy)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps? I have used the mtcars dataset. Replace the variables with your own.

You would add your filter as well

```
mtcars
mt2 <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(!is.na(gear)) %>%
  select(cyl, gear) %>% #select the columns you want
  group_by(cyl) %>%  # for you it is VSNT
  count %>%  #because it isn't an integer
  ungroup %>% # so that values aren't 1
  mutate(prop_n = n/sum(n))
mt2
```

This will give you proportions.